# How to check grep is empty when set -e is enabled?

Tags: bash, grep, sh

How to check `grep` is empty when `set -e` is enabled?

```bash
set -e

# ... lots of other lines that need set -e

echo foo | grep bar
EXIT_CODE=$?

if [  "${EXIT_CODE}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "is there"
else
  echo "isn't there"
fi

# ... lots of other lines that need set -e
```

The script will stop when `EXIT_CODE != 0`, instead of printing "isn't there", which is the wanted behavior in this snippet.

Obviously, I can just unset e (`set +e`) before and after the grep check.

```bash
set -e

# ... lots of other lines that need set -e

set +e
echo foo | grep bar
EXIT_CODE=$?
set -e

if [  "${EXIT_CODE}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "is there"
else
  echo "isn't there"
fi

# ... lots of other lines that need set -e
```

**Is there another better more elegant solution?**

Comment: Note that if you just do the standard check with `if echo foo | grep bar; then ....` instead of explicitly assigning `$?` to a variable, then the default behavior of `set -e` (whatever that is!!, see decades of discussion about the ambiguity of the expression "default behavior of set -e") should do what you want.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks. `if echo foo | grep bar`, which in this case is empty, will enter the if or the else?

Comment: If `grep` matches the pattern, it will return 0 and the `if` clause is entered.  If `grep` does not match the pattern, it will return non-zero and the else clause is entered.

Comment: Do read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Interesting one. Which opposes to this: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/